# Mx not resolving to IP when pointing to its own domain

Tags: postfix

I'm running postfix and have setup previously a mail server on a domain e.g. mail.firstdomain.com. Recently I added another domain e.g. mail.seconddomain.com.

In the MX records for the second domain, I copied the same setup as the first domain, and just changed the relevant parts. However, I could not receive emails from outside the server - just internally. I then changed the mx record of seconddomain.com to the primary myhostname: mail.firstdomain.com, and now it is working.

What have I missed in my configuration stopping me from using mail.seconddomain.com?

Here is the output of postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 40960000
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, mail.$mydomain
mydomain = firstdomain.com
myhostname = mail.firstdomain.com
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination, firstdomain.com, seconddomain.com
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,   permit_mynetworks,        reject_invalid_hostname,        reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unauth_destination,  reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,             permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
soft_bounce = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = mail.seconddomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: If `mail.seconddomain.com` resolved to the same IP as `mail.firstdomain.com`, the mails should have reached your server and thus the rejection messages should be visible in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

This method may not suit your use-case, though I usually put additional domains into `virtual(5)`:

```
# postconf relay_domains virtual_alias_maps
relay_domains = $mydestination
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Where `$mydestination` contains the equivalent of your first domain domain and hostnames. The virtual map then contains:

```
otherdomain.edu   anything
someone@otherdomain.edu    foo@firstdom.edu
...
```